# Manager classes for Objects

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, subclass

Moving from C#/C++ to PHP OOP has proven a bit problematic as I am not sure it is standard to design the code layout in the same manner. As that is the case, I am curious if the following would be considered problematic or wrong when it comes to PHP.

- CDeviceManager class (1 initiated)
- CDevice class
- Keep a private array of CDevice in the CDeviceManager class
- Use public methods to fetch devices, search devices, etc.

The most problematic question however is populating each CDevice from a MySQL Database. Would it be safe to include my Database class directly into CDeviceManager and Populate CDevice Array in CDeviceManager Construct?

A lot of what I have read says it is smart to separate the business logic from the view, where I feel this method would do just that. I have not seen many other projects that appear to use this approach though, why I am worried I may be missing something.

Comment: OOP isn't language-dependent. It's implementation in certain language, however, may be specific - but it you're aware of what is OOP and what are it's principles, then I don't see where can be the problem. Just implement your structure and logic. Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you say "Database class" do you mean `PDO`?

Comment: It is a MYSQLi class I just grabbed to use for now https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Comment: wow .. that's terrible

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to separate your business logic from data storage system.  I recommend using dependency injection to get your job done.  The exact implementation would depend on your needs (and project size), but to get an idea here's would be what I would do:

```
class CDeviceManager
{
    private $db;  //holder for your database
    private $cdevices = array();
    //more properties here

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
         $this->db = $db; //database connection has now been injected into your class
    }

    //more methods here
}
```

Then somewhere along the line when you create your `CDeviceManager` object you can inject the database connection.

```
$cdm = new CDeviceManager( new Database(...) );
```

Your `Database` class would likely be a wrapper for `PDO` or `MySQLi` or whatever database API you would want to use.  You could also go farther and have `CDeviceManager` implement some kind of interface that relate to various CRUD functions in your database.  Best part though, is you can test this a whole lot easier because now you can swap out your database connection with a mock/test database so you don't inadvertently screw up your production database.

```
$cdm = new CDeviceManager( new MockDatabase(...) );
```

or

```
$testdb = new TestDatabase(...);
$cdm = new CDeviceManager( $testdb );
```

So yes, in the end it is good to separate the database connection from your domain models.  Some recommend going even farther and making sure that your domain models are completely ignorant to the storage mechanism in general, this way you could be flexible on your storage system/persistence layer.  E.g:

```
$cdm = new CDeviceManager( new FileRetriever() );  //Maybe you are storing stuff in a flat file
```

Hope that helps clear things up a little bit.